# (Bukkit) (Java) How can I get item in first slot and second slot when a player open an anvil and How can I set the output as an item?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, inventory

What i'm asking for is a way to get the items in the first and the second slot and set the output and when a player take the output i need to remove items i first and second slot.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we have [Slot number info](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#Inventory_slot_numbers)

We also have a method to get items that require an integer.

> Try `player.getInventory().getItem(paramInt)`

This SHOULD get the slot number you pass to it.

For the output(Guessing your saying how to set the item for a slot).

> Try `player.getInventory().setItem(paramInt, paramItemStack)`

To remove items in a slot just set it to air.

So just simply find the slot you want in "Slot number info" above and set it or get it.